# Could not write content: could not initialize proxy - no Session through reference chain

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jackson

I'm trying to write a relatively generic REST implementation to support general CRUD on all my DB entities. Using spring with hibernate and jackson.

However, for some reason, the GET (specific item id) operation fails with the error listed in question.

BrakeType.java (model):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BrakeType")
public class BrakeType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "brakeCode", nullable = false)
    private String brakeCode;

    @Column(name = "brakeDescription", nullable = false)
    private String brakeDescription;

    ...getters, setters, toString()
}
```

AbstractDao.java

```
public abstract class AbstractDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    protected Session getSession() { return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); }
    public void persist(Object entity) { getSession().persist(entity); }
    public void delete(Object entity) { getSession().delete(entity); }
}
```

GenericDao.java

```
public interface GenericDao<T> {
  T save(T obj);
  List<T> findAll();
  void deleteById(Integer id);
  T findById(Integer id);
  T update(T obj);
}
```

GenericDaoOps.java

```
public abstract class GenericDaoOps<T> extends AbstractDao implements GenericDao<T> {
  public abstract Class<T> getPClass();
  public String getTableName() { return getPClass().getSimpleName(); }
  @Override
  public T save(T obj) { persist(obj); return obj; }
  @Override
  public List<T> findAll() {
      Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(getPClass(), getPClass().getSimpleName());
      return (List<T>) criteria.list();
  }
  @Override
  public void deleteById(Integer id) { getSession().delete(findById(id)); }
  @Override
  public T findById(Integer id) { return getSession().load(getPClass(), id); }
  @Override
  public T update(T obj) { getSession().update(obj);  return obj; }
}
```

BrakeTypeDao.java:

```
public interface BrakeTypeDao extends GenericDao<BrakeType> { }
```

BrakeTypeDaoImpl.java

```
public class BrakeTypeDaoImpl extends GenericDaoOps<BrakeType> implements BrakeTypeDao {
    @Override
    public Class<BrakeType> getPClass() {
        return BrakeType.class;
    }
}
```

BrakeTypeController.java:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
@Api(value = "/lists", description = "REST Api SIMA application - administration")
@Transactional
public class SimaBrakeTypeController {
    private static final String obj_name = "brake type";
    private static final String obj_name_api = "/lists/brake_type";
    private static final String obj_names = "brake types";
    private static final String obj_names_api = "/lists/brake_types";

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloController.class);

    @Autowired
    private Interfaces.BrakeTypeDao dao;

    @ApiOperation(value = "List of all " + obj_names, notes = "List of all " + obj_names + " for SIMA system.", response = BrakeType[].class)
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, message = "OK") })
    @RequestMapping(value = obj_names_api, method =  RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<SmartHttpResult> simaBrakeTypeGetAll() {
        final List<BrakeType> usrList = dao.findAll();
        logger.debug("GET ALL " + obj_names.toUpperCase() + ":");

        return Response.getHttpResult(usrList, usrList.size() > 0, "/", obj_names.toUpperCase().replace(" ", "_") + "_NOT_FOUND");
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = obj_name, notes = obj_name + " for current ID.", response = BrakeType.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, message = "OK") })
    @RequestMapping(value = obj_name_api + "/{id}/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<SmartHttpResult> simaBrakeTypeGet(@PathVariable("id") final Integer id) {
        BrakeType obj = dao.findById(id);
        logger.debug(String.format("GET %S: %d", obj_name, id));

        return Response.getHttpResult(obj, obj != null, "/", String.format("%S_NOT_FOUND", obj_name.replace(" ", "_")));
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Adding " + obj_name, notes = "Add new " + obj_name + ". Returns id of new " + obj_name + ".", response = BrakeType.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED, message = "Created") })
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @RequestMapping(value = obj_name_api, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<SmartHttpResult> simaBrakeTypeAdd(@RequestBody final BrakeType obj) {
        BrakeType inserted = dao.save(obj);

        // for Mockito (unit test) simulate insert ona database
        if (dao.getClass().getName().contains("Mockito") && obj.getId() != null)
            inserted = obj;
        logger.debug(String.format("INSERT %S: %s", obj_name, inserted.toString()));
        return Response.getHttpResult(inserted, inserted != null, obj_name.toUpperCase() + "_CREATED", obj_name.toUpperCase() + "USER_NOT_CREATED");
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Update " + obj_name, notes = "Update/edit " + obj_name + ".Returns complete user object.",
            response = BrakeType.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, message = "OK") })
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @RequestMapping(value = obj_name_api, method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<SmartHttpResult> simaBrakeTypeEdit(@RequestBody final BrakeType obj) {
        BrakeType inserted = dao.update(obj);

        logger.debug(String.format("UPDATE %S: %s", obj_name, inserted.toString()));
        return Response.getHttpResult(inserted, inserted != null, obj_name.toUpperCase() + "_UPDATED",
                obj_name.toUpperCase() + "_NOT_UPDATED");
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Delete " + obj_name,
            notes = "Delete current " + obj_name + ". Returns deleted " + obj_name + " ID.",
            response = BrakeType.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, message = "OK") })
    @RequestMapping(value = obj_name_api + "/{id}/", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<SmartHttpResult> simaBrakeTypeDelete(@PathVariable("id") final Integer id) {
        dao.deleteById(id);

        logger.debug(String.format("DELETE %S: %d", obj_name, id));
        return Response.getHttpResult(id, id != null, obj_name.toUpperCase() + "_DELETED", obj_name.toUpperCase() + "_NOT_DELETED");
    }
}
```

All operations work, except for GET /lists/break_type/{id}/

Exception thrown:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Could not write content: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: sima.model.SmartHttpResult["result"]->sima.model.BrakeType_$$_jvstdfd_3["id"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: sima.model.SmartHttpResult["result"]->sima.model.BrakeType_$$_jvstdfd_3["id"])

type Exception report

message Could not write content: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: sima.model.SmartHttpResult["result"]->sima.model.BrakeType_$$_jvstdfd_3["id"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: sima.model.SmartHttpResult["result"]->sima.model.BrakeType_$$_jvstdfd_3["id"])

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: sima.model.SmartHttpResult["result"]->sima.model.BrakeType_$$_jvstdfd_3["id"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: sima.model.SmartHttpResult["result"]->sima.model.BrakeType_$$_jvstdfd_3["id"])
  org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:271)
  org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:167)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:185)
  org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:127)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
  org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: sima.model.SmartHttpResult["result"]->sima.model.BrakeType_$$_jvstdfd_3["id"])
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:210)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:177)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:199)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:683)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1387)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:889)
  org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:264)
  org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:167)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:185)
  org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:127)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
  org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
  org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:148)
  org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:266)
  org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:68)
  sima.model.BrakeType_$$_jvstdfd_3.getId(BrakeType_$$_jvstdfd_3.java)
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:654)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1387)
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:889)
  org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:264)
  org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:167)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:185)
  org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:127)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
  org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

What am I missing?

Edit: I just discovered, that if I change GenericDaoOps.java, function findById:

```
@Override
public T findById(Integer id) {
    //return getSession().load(getPClass(), id);
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(getPClass());
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
    return (T) criteria.uniqueResult();
}
```

The thing starts working...

What's the difference???

Comment: does your brakeType model has "id" ?

Comment: Yes, it does. Please see OP edit: I found the culprit, but don't understand why that's a problem...

Comment: Is it because you are not passing a primitive integer id?

Comment: I don't know. How would `Integer id` not be a primitive integer or null (but null is impossible due to routing).